# Kivy error in MacOS Virtual Box Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, macos, kivy

I installed the Kivy library using the conda environment, but I get this error, and everything works on Linux and Windows

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin/python /Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/<APP>/kivy_test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/ilya/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-05-28_88.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr 24 2020, 16:27:41) 
[GCC Clang 9.0.1 ]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
Core Image is now using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow.
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'Failed creating OpenGL pixel format'
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 290, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 232, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Have you disabled hardware acceleration? If you have you should enable it

Comment: Everything is included except 3D acceleration

Comment: That's the problem. You should include it

Comment: The same error(

Comment: Try setting the `KIVY_WINDOW` environment variable to 'pygame'. Use the information from here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html

Comment: `import os
os.environ["KIVY_WINDOW"] = "pygame"` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214905/discussion-between-droptop-and-pikro).